# How to get pointer of Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I am passing a fragment to an activity using the xml `fragment` tag. Is there a way to get a pointer of that exact fragment instance from within the code?

Answer (score 0):

Pointer?

If you mean a reference to the object, call `findFragmentById()` on the appropriate `FragmentManager`, sometime after you have inflated the layout containing the `<fragment>` element.

Comment: Yes, I meant reference. I will try it out. Thanks!